# How can I know whether Finger has entered a Widget or not while sliding over Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get a true while finger in randomly sliding over the screen and enters a particular widget and false if finger gets out of that widget.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be achieved using the `Draggable` and `DragTarget` widgets:

refer to those topics:

[Drag a UI element](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/drag-a-widget)

[Draggable Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html#:%7E:text=When%20a%20draggable%20widget%20recognizes,data%20carried%20by%20the%20draggable.)

[DragTarget Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are no mouse devices on mobile, so users don't have the luxury of using hover effects. Using a hover effect on mobile apps causes buttons to stay stuck in the hovered state when tapped. This stickiness not only confuses users, but it frustrates them when they're forced to double-tap buttons to initiate an action. The alternative is the Inkwell widget which will show a splash when the user will enter said widget.

Hope this helps.